# How to execute the further code only after the successful JSON response?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am very beginner in swift and I am trying to fetch some JSON Data from an api and then creating an array from that Data.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
    .responseJSON
    {
        response in
        let JSON = response.result.value
        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
        let Data = response.objectForKey("data")!
        for slot in timeSlot as! NSDictionary
        {
            let json = slot.value
            let availability = json as! NSDictionary
            let myavailable = availability.objectForKey("available")!
            let slotTime = availability.objectForKey("time")!
            if (myavailable as! NSNumber == 1)
            {
                self.fetchSlot.append(slotTime as! String)
            }
        }
        for x in self.mySlot
        {
            for c in self.fetchSlot
            {
                if (c == x)
                {
                    self.availableSlot.append(x)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to print the "self.availableslot" in the same viewDid load function. 
But it always returning an empty array, because it is compiling before all the JSON data is fetched.

Please if there is any way how can I use reload method or completion handler kind of things to get my job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
func performAlamoFireRequest(completion: () -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseJSON {
        response in

        let JSON = response.result.value
        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
        let Data = response.objectForKey("data")!

        for slot in timeSlot as! NSDictionary {
            let json = slot.value
            let availability = json as! NSDictionary
            let myavailable = availability.objectForKey("available")!
            let slotTime = availability.objectForKey("time")!
            if (myavailable as! NSNumber == 1) {
                self.fetchSlot.append(slotTime as! String)
            }
        }

        for x in self.mySlot {

            for c in self.fetchSlot {
                if (c == x) {
                    self.availableSlot.append(x)
                }
            }
        }
        completion()
    }
}

performAlamoFireRequest() {
//code to perform after here
}
```

Comment: How to call performAlamoFireRequest function in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Call it whenever you had your code written originally before I stuck it in a function of it's own.

Comment: It is asking me to pass parameters. 
I wanted to call performAlamoFireRequest function in my viewDidLoad only.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        performAlamoFireRequest()

        }

Comment: Then pass whatever variables you need to pass into the function... Just make sure to keep completion: () -> Void as a parameter.